# Prove that $a(u-u_{h},u-u_{h})\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, calculus-of-variations

Assume that $a$ is bilinear, symmetric and positive definite form, $u\in X$ and $u_{h}\in X_{h}\subset X$. I  know the following fact:
$$a(u-u_{h},u_{h})=0$$ 
Frm positive definiteness $a(u-u_{h},u-u_{h})>0$. I am trying to show that the equality applies:
$$a(u-u_{h},u-u_{h})= 0$$
I am not able to go further, any hints or suggestions are welcome?

Comment: Here is something I don't understand, if $a$ is bilinear, symmetric and positive definite form then we know that $a(v,v)\ge 0$ for all $v\in X$, just apply that at $v=u-u_h$.

Comment: @user37238, thank you for the reply. I agree with you, positive definiteness implies >0 but I am trying to see when the equality applies, I have modified my question to that effect

Comment: This is not true Take $u_h=e_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $u=(1,1)$. Note that $u_h-u=e_2$. Let $a$ be the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We have that $a(u-u_h,u_h)=(e_2,e_1)=0$ while $(u-u_h,u-u_h)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bilinear, symmetric and positive-definite form is a scalar product: $a(v,v) \geq 0$ for every $v$, and $a(v,v)=0$ if and only if $v=0$.

Of course I am assuming that positive-definite is intended here in the strong sense: usually the condition "$a(v,v) \geq 0$ for every $v$" is called *positive semidefinite*.

Hence the equality means exactly that $u=u_h$.